# How to validate image on update in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii, insert-update

I have put validation in yii for images. It works during record creation but when updating the form it also validates the image field. I don't want to update the image every time. How can the rules be set for this?
Thanks.

Comment: it is not clear to me, do you want ti validate image on update or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very easy while , updating the file or image. You need to create a scenario for this e.g if you have rules.

```
public function rules()
    {
          return [
            [['contents'], 'string'],
            [['status', 'parent_id', 'sort_order'], 'integer'],
            [['status','title'], 'required'],
            [['image'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'],
            [['title', 'slug'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
```

then in your Controller on create action use this code.

```
    $model->setScenario('create');
```

pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks I used your code it was very help full and its working nicely.